# Fill column by repeating sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like below, I want to insert certain values within a repetitive pattern (Sets of 4). So that my dataframe looks like 'df2' (Shown beneath 'df'). I would like this pattern to continue until the rows end (in this case is 10 rows down).

```
df:

ID    Descrip    Code
1     NaN
2     3
3     4
4     7
5     NaN
6     11
7     NaN
8     20
9     22
10    15

df2:

ID    Descrip    Code
1     NaN        MS
2     3          MU
3     4          MN
4     7          MO
5     NaN        MS
6     11         MU
7     NaN        MN
8     20         MO
9     22         MS
10    15         MU
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) here:

```
from itertools import cycle

i = iter(['MS', 'MU', 'MN','MO'])
df['Code'] = df.index.map(dict(zip(df.index, cycle(i))))
```

---

```
print(df)

   ID  Descrip Code
0   1      NaN   MS
1   2      3.0   MU
2   3      4.0   MN
3   4      7.0   MO
4   5      NaN   MS
5   6     11.0   MU
6   7      NaN   MN
7   8     20.0   MO
8   9     22.0   MS
9  10     15.0   MU
```

---

Another approach, `NumPy` based, would be to [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) the sequence up to `df.shape[0]`. Note that, as mentioned in the docs, this method fills the new array with repeated copies of the input array:

```
a = np.array(['MS', 'MU', 'MN','MO'])
df['Code'] = np.resize(a, df.shape[0])
```

---

The first approach works by creating a dictionary mapping the index to the sequence, where the iterator has just been cycled around as many times as necessary to fit the dataframe's `index` size. This works since `zip` will be combining elements from both iterables until the first one is exhausted, which will always be the non-infinite one, quite obviously :)

```
print(dict(zip(df.index, cycle(i))))
# {0: 'MS', 1: 'MU', 2: 'MN', 3: 'MO', 4: 'MS', 5: 'MU'...
```

Then we can assign it to the new column by mapping the index with the created dictionary

Answer (score 0):

not the most elegant solution but quite intuitave

```
#create a dataframe with 10 rows
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ID'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

#create a list containg the seqence of values we want to repeat
values = ['a','b','c','d']

#define the number of times this series can be repeated for a given dataframe length
n_repeats = len(df) % len(values)

#define new column as a list
repeated_values = []

#repeatedly extend the list
for iteration in range(1,n_repeats+2):
    repeated_values.extend(values)

#create a column which takes the repeated values and stops at the length of the dataframe
df['repeated_values'] = repeated_values[0:len(df)]
```